# Get all data of foreign key in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm

Currently i am doing this to get branch table data:

```
$smlist = SM::where('branch_id','=',$branchid)->select('id','name','branch_id')->get();
    foreach ($smlist as $sm) {
      $sm->b = SM::find($sm->id)->branch;
    }
```

Where branch_id is foreign key, also I set belongsTo in SM table.
This is working fine for me but I am finding way to use it with in single query.
How can i get this data using single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [eager load](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) your relationship using `with()`:

```
$smlist = SM::with('branch')
            ->where('branch_id','=',$branchid)
            ->select('id','name','branch_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: You need to select the branch name too :)

Comment: @lukasgeiter Thanks for answer. Can i use select on branch to get specify field with in this query?

Comment: @AdminBonanza That should work, yes. Just use the `table.column` syntax to avoid ambiguous column names.

Comment: @AdminBonanza Maybe I misunderstood you. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a join, here you can find the documentation http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins

I think you can use something like this:

```
SM::->join('branch', 'branch.id', '=', 'sm.branch_id')
.where('sm.branch_id','=',$branchid)
->select('sm.id','sm.name','sm.branch_id','branch.name')
->get();
```